# How to track mouse position during drag drop event

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I am drag and dropping a button using the buttons mousedown and mousemove event, and the receiving panels drag drop event. It works fine. The button moves to its new location (within the same panel it started in) when the mouse is released.

I want to show the user a ghost image of the control while it's being moved, so to do this I think need to know where the mouse is before the button is released.

I have tried the button.mousemove event but this doesn't keep firing as I move the mouse once I have started the drag operation.

The doDragDrop call is in mousemove.

There seem to be a lot of people asking the same sort of question on here, but none for vb.net

Comment: As soon as I click and start to drag, the mousemove stop firing. I put a debug.writeline in there to give me e.x and e.y to see how they change

Comment: look at the DragOver event - it supplies the X and Y during drag events